# Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs

I'm new on React and I'm trying to make a CRUD. The form inside `<div className="conteudo">` is working flawlessly. Next I swaped `function App()` by `class App extends Component { render() {` and wrote the code to handle Facebook auth. It compiled well, with no errors on terminal.

But in the browser it shows me the (in)famous message "Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component."

As a complete noob, what I'ḿ doing wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Bellow is my code...

=======================================================

```
import React, { useState, Component } from 'react';
import api from './services/api';
import './App.css';
import logotipo from './assets/logotipo.png';
import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login';

class App extends Component  {
  render() {

    const responseFacebook = (response) => {
    }

    const [nome, setNome] = useState('');
    const [ra, setRa] = useState('');
    const [telefone, setTelefone] = useState('');
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [senha, setSenha] = useState('');

    async function processaSubmit (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      const response =  await api.post('/users', {
        nome: nome,
        ra: ra,
        telefone: telefone,
        email: email,
        senha: senha,
      })

      console.log(response)
    }

    return (
      <div className="contenedor">

        <img src={logotipo} alt="Um logotipo qualquer" />

        <div className="App">
        <h1>LOGIN WITH FACEBOOK AND GOOGLE</h1>

        <FacebookLogin
          appId="381163456103277" //APP ID NOT CREATED YET
          fields="name,email,picture"
          callback={responseFacebook}
        />

        </div>

        <div className="conteudo">
          <p className="big">Bem vindes ao <strong>Sistema de Textos CAPed</strong>. <br />Faça seu cadastro para aproveitar o nosso <strong>acervo</strong>.</p>

          <button className="btn" type="Submit">Usar login do Facebook</button>

          <p className="big"></p>
          <p className="big">Ou faça o cadastro <strong>manualmente</strong> preenchendo o formulário abaixo.</p>

          <form onSubmit={processaSubmit}>

            <label htmlFor="Nome">Nome</label>
            <input 
              type="txt" 
              id="nome" 
              placeholder="Nome e sobrenome, pfvr"
              value={nome}
              onChange={event => setNome(event.target.value)}
            >
            </input>

            <label htmlFor="Ra">RA</label>
            <input 
              type="txt" 
              id="ra" 
              placeholder="Seu RA"
              value={ra}
              onChange={event => setRa(event.target.value)}
            >
            </input>

            <label htmlFor="telefone">Telefone</label>
            <input 
              type="tnumber" 
              id="telefone" 
              placeholder="Podemos precisar ;-)"
              value={telefone}
              onChange={event => setTelefone(event.target.value)}
            >
            </input>

            <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
            <input 
              type="email" 
              id="email" 
              placeholder="Digite seu melhor email"
              value={email}
              onChange={event => setEmail(event.target.value)}
            >
            </input>

            <label htmlFor="senha">Senha</label>
            <input 
              type="password" 
              id="senha" 
              placeholder="Digite uma senha bacana"
              value={senha}
              onChange={event => setSenha(event.target.value)}
            >
            </input>

            <p className="little">&nbsp;</p>

            <button className="btn" type="Submit">Fazer meu cadastro</button>

          </form>

          <p className="little"></p>
          <p className="little">Já tem cadastro mas não lembre a senha? Clique bem <strong>aqui</strong>.</p>

        </div>

      </div>
    );
  };
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Basically you can not use hooks inside a class... You must use a function...

Answer (score 0):

To use hooks, you must implement a function component. The following should help you get started. Essentially, rather than having a `render` method, your JSX is returned from the function.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import api from './services/api';
import './App.css';
import logotipo from './assets/logotipo.png';
import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login';

const App = () => {
  const responseFacebook = (response) => {}
  const [nome, setNome] = useState('');
  const [ra, setRa] = useState('');
  const [telefone, setTelefone] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [senha, setSenha] = useState('');

  async function processaSubmit (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const response =  await api.post('/users', {
      nome: nome,
      ra: ra,
      telefone: telefone,
      email: email,
      senha: senha,
    })

    console.log(response)
  }

  return ( ... )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: In fact, I need to understand the logic behind ´App = ()` :-)